# Where is some good example code for PHP photo upload?

Tags: php, file-upload

Nobody seems to have tied together all of the example code in various StackOverflow questions into a good, well-put-together sample of how to handle a photo upload. Here's my start... please help improve it.

Here's our setup:

- Our file upload control is named `$file`, e.g. `<input type="file" name="<?= $file ?>" />`.
- We want to save the photo to `$photosPath`, e.g. `$photosPath = "/photos/"`.
- We want the filename to be `$targetFilename . ".jpg"`, where e.g. `$targetFilename` could be from a username text field in our upload form.
- We want to store the resulting file path in `$filePath`, e.g. for insertion into a database.
- We want to only accept .jpgs.
- We want to only accept files of at most `$maxSize` bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my shot at it:

```
// Given: $file, $targetFilename, $photosPath, $maxSize
$filePath = NULL;
if (array_key_exists($_FILES, $file)
    && $_FILES[$file]['size'] != 0
    && $_FILES[$file]['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK)
{
    if ($_FILES[$file]['size'] > $maxSize)
    {
        throw new Exception("The uploaded photo was too large; the maximum size is $maxSize bytes.");
    }

    $imageData = getimagesize($_FILES[$file]['tmp_name']);
    $extension = image_type_to_extension($imageData[2]);
    if ($extension != ".jpg" && $extension != ".jpeg")
    {
        throw new Exception("Only .jpg photos are allowed.");
    }

    $possibleFilePath = $photosPath . $targetFilename . ".jpg";
    if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$file]['tmp_name'],
                            $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $possibleFilePath)
    {
        throw new Exception("Could not save the uploaded photo to the server.");
    }

    $filePath = $possibleFilePath;
}
```